# UWP Find Fullscreen exit reason

Tags: c#, uwp

In my UWP app I'm reacting to the `Window.Current.SizeChanged` event to see when the app enters or leaves the fullscreen mode.

Is there a way to figure out if the fullscreen mode was left because of User interaction (i.e. clicking the leave fullscreen button in the title bar) or if for some other reason the app returned to windowed mode? This can happen sometimes for example if there are changes to the PCs displays etc.

I'd like to re-apply the fullscreen mode whenever it wasn't explicitly exited by the user.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to figure out if the fullscreen mode was left because
>   of User interaction (i.e. clicking the leave fullscreen button in the
>   title bar) or if for some other reason the app returned to windowed
>   mode?

I'm sorry to say that there is no such UWP API could detect how the window exits the full-screen mode. 
I also searched in UWP's documents, but I can't find a way to implement your requirement.

My suggestion is that you could offer a choice to the users asking if they want the app showing in full-screen mode. If they want to keep the full-screen mode, you could subscribe to the SizeChanged event and keep the windows always in the full-screen mode. If the users don't, then you don't need to subscribe to the event and just let the customer decide the size.